# How to display elements inside v-for step by step on click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array with data. By default only the first element should be visible.

By clicking on the YES or NO button i need to show the element whose id corresponds to yes_section or no_section (depending on which button were clicked)

For example if in the Example 1 block we click on "no 4" button, then the Example 4 block appears below, and if we click on "yes 2", then the Example 2 block should appear.

Thanks in advance! =)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    stepsData: [
        {
        id: "1",
        yes_section: "2",
        no_section: "4",
        name: "Example 1"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        yes_section: "5",
        no_section: "3",
        name: "Example 2"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        yes_section: "2",
        no_section: "4",
        name: "Example 3"
      },
      {
        id: "4",
        yes_section: "2",
        no_section: "4",
        name: "Example 4"
      },
      {
        id: "5",
        yes_section: "2",
        no_section: "4",
        name: "Example 5"
      },
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
.step {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div 
  v-for="(step, id) in stepsData" 
  :key="step.id"
  class="step"
>
  <div class="legal-aid__step-question" v-html="step.name"></div>
    <button>YES {{ step.yes_section }}</button>
    <button>NO {{ step.no_section }}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should save step_id and use computed properties (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to show needed step info

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    active_step_id: "1",
    stepsData: [
        {
        id: "1",
        yes_section: "2",
        no_section: "4",
        name: "Example 1"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        yes_section: "5",
        no_section: "3",
        name: "Example 2"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        yes_section: "2",
        no_section: "4",
        name: "Example 3"
      },
      {
        id: "4",
        yes_section: "2",
        no_section: "4",
        name: "Example 4"
      },
      {
        id: "5",
        yes_section: "2",
        no_section: "4",
        name: "Example 5"
      },
    ]
  }),
  
  computed: {
    active_step() {
      return this.stepsData.find(step => step.id === this.active_step_id)
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.step {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div 
  class="step"
>
  <div class="legal-aid__step-question" v-html="active_step.name"></div>
    <button @click.prevent="active_step_id = active_step.yes_section">YES {{ active_step.yes_section }}</button>
    <button @click.prevent="active_step_id = active_step.no_section">NO {{ active_step.no_section }}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```